# @ContentView in Sliding Menu activity

Tags: android, roboguice, slidingmenu

I'm trying to inject the `contentview` after extending `SlidingFragmentActivity` from sliding menu library. But I'm getting error like

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Both setBehindContentView must be called in onCreate in addition to setContentView".
```

But it works fine if i set the content inside `onCreate`. Can any one suggest solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `setBehindContentView` yourself even when using `@ContentView`. The `@ContentView` annotation calls `setContentView` for you in the `onCreate` of the super class (RoboActivity), but not `setBehindContentView`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found solution for it

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
setBehindContentView(menu);
```

try this one . Its helpful for me.